# display: none; won't hide the element when used in media query CSS3

Tags: html, css

Here's what markup looks like:

```
<aside>
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="widget-title">
        <h4>General Info:</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="widget-body">
        <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $age; ?></p>
      </div>
</aside>
```

This what normal style looks like:

```
aside {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #9D9D9D;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and here is what media query style looks like:

```
@media (max-width: 610px) {
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I know my syntax is right because when I use:

```
@media (max-width: 610px) {
  aside {
     background-color: red;
  }
}
```

It turns red when I rescale.
But it won't go away when I use display: none;

Comment: i tried your code is working fine. What browser you are using to test ?

Comment: I tried both browser is working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/st89jd4u/4/.
You just control the size of the browser you will see it hide

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and Firefox and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is the only css reference in the page? It might be possible aside is overriden by another css reference, worth to check in the developer toolbar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @radiant It was bootstrap causing it to be overridden to display: block;

Comment: Glad it helped, cheers.